# httpClient Upload file to SiteAssets

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

How can I upload a file to the current web SiteAssets or document library using the spfx httpClient? Is there a code sample I can learn from?

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer using the new PnP-JS-Core to do file uploading.  It's a nice library from PnP and provides a fluent API for the REST endpoints - as a bonus it works with traditional, sprequestexecutor or node-fetch and supports REST batching.

<del>https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core/</del>
https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickrodgers/

The Files.Add method would be here:

<del>http://officedev.github.io/PnP-JS-Core/classes/_sharepoint_rest_files_.files.html#add</del>

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/files/#adding-files

Comment: That's awesome, @JohnLiu. I have to give it a shot.

Comment: All three links are non functioning.... Can you update?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any code samples specifically for the new framework but you can refer to the [SharePoint REST API File Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_File) for the available operations or [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx) that demonstrates how to upload a file using the REST API. Note that both the documentation and example assume you're using the cross-domain library which is *not* needed in the new framework so the URLs to the services are going to be a bit different. For example in the new framework you don't need the SP.AppContextSite(@target) portions of the url.

Hope that helps